# Why doesn't the producer-consumer stop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, queue, producer-consumer

I've found an example representing producer-consumer with two threads. But, when I send a signal to the process to stop, it doesn't. It expects second signal e.g. `SIGKILL` to completely stop. I thought the problem is with `task_done()` but it seems not.

```
import time

import queue
import threading
import random


class Producer(threading.Thread):
    """
    Produces random integers to a list
    """

    def __init__(self, queue):
        """
        Constructor.

        @param queue queue synchronization object
        """
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        """
        Thread run method. Append random integers to the integers
        list at random time.
        """
        while True:
            integer = random.randint(0, 256)
            self.queue.put(integer)
            print('%d put to queue by %s' % (integer, self.name))
            time.sleep(1)


class Consumer(threading.Thread):
    """
    Consumes random integers from a list
    """

    def __init__(self, queue):
        """
        Constructor.

        @param integers list of integers
        @param queue queue synchronization object
        """
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        """
        Thread run method. Consumes integers from list
        """
        while True:
            integer = self.queue.get()
            print('%d popped from list by %s' % (integer, self.name))
            self.queue.task_done()


def main():
    q = queue.Queue()
    t1 = Producer(q)
    t2 = Consumer(q)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
210 put to queue by Thread-1
210 popped from list by Thread-2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abc/PycharmProjects/untitled1/ssid.py", line 74, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/abc/PycharmProjects/untitled1/ssid.py", line 69, in main
    t1.join()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1056, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1072, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
244 put to queue by Thread-1
244 popped from list by Thread-2
85 put to queue by Thread-1
85 popped from list by Thread-2
160 put to queue by Thread-1
160 popped from list by Thread-2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because only the main-thread get's stopped by the KeyboardInterrupt. You can watch this by letting your child threads print `threading.enumerate()` which returns all alive threads + the main thread.

```
import time
import queue
import threading
import random


class Producer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            integer = random.randint(0, 256)
            self.queue.put(integer)
            print(f'{integer} put to queue by {self.name} '
                  f'threads: {threading.enumerate()}')
            time.sleep(1)


class Consumer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            integer = self.queue.get()
            print(f'{integer} popped from list by {self.name} '
                  f'threads:{threading.enumerate()}')
            self.queue.task_done()


def main():
    q = queue.Queue()
    t1 = Producer(q)
    t2 = Consumer(q)
    # t1.daemon = True
    # t2.daemon = True
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('got KeyboardInterrupt')
```

Example Output with KeyboardInterrupt. Note the MainThread listed as 'stopped' after the KeyboardInterrupt:

```
97 put to queue by Thread-1 threads: [<_MainThread(MainThread, started 
139810293606208)>, <Producer(Thread-1, started 139810250913536)>, 
<Consumer(Thread-2, started 139810242520832)>]
97 popped from list by Thread-2 threads:[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 
139810293606208)>, <Producer(Thread-1, started 139810250913536)>, 
<Consumer(Thread-2, started 139810242520832)>]
got KeyboardInterrupt
92 put to queue by Thread-1 threads: [<_MainThread(MainThread, stopped 
139810293606208)>, <Producer(Thread-1, started 139810250913536)>, 
<Consumer(Thread-2, started 139810242520832)>]
92 popped from list by Thread-2 threads:[<_MainThread(MainThread, stopped 
139810293606208)>, <Producer(Thread-1, started 139810250913536)>, 
<Consumer(Thread-2, started 139810242520832)>]
```

You could make the child-threads daemons to let them exit with the main-thread. But that should be only considered in case your threads don't hold any resources:

> Note Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an Event [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event).

The better way would be to catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` like in the code above and send a sentinel value over the queue to the child-threads to let them know they should finish, allowing them to do clean-up before exit.